# UICollectionView cell imageview not show image, but it's show background color xcode

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell)
    {
//        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor]; // it's work
        CollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//        UIImageView *iser = [[UIImageView alloc] init];  // it's not working
//        iser.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];  // it's not working
//        [cell.CellImageView addSubview:iser];  // it's not working
        cell.CellImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];  // it's not working
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(106, 107);
}

-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

This is my code I am trying to show a image (at least) in all collection view but it's not working any one tell me what I did wrong

That comment 4 lines are alternative lines I am already tried that 4 comment lines and this also

```
cell.CellImagView.image = [CollectionViewImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

What I thought first I need show at least only one image in collectionviewCell and then move to array

If I comment cell color collectionviewcell show nothing

Comment: where you defined CollectionViewImageArray?

Comment: in viewWillAppear... @AkashShinde array is working perfectly i am check that array value in table view it's show image.. now array is not my problem collection view cell not show that a single image also.. in xib cell (attributes inspector) imageview declared a image that's also not shown.. :(

Comment: @AkashShinde thanks for ur effect to find ans..

Comment: Is `cell.CellImageView` nil? What's its frame? `cell.CellImageView.backgroundColor = someColor` works?